# How to change the table row value in existing table in jquery?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have one jquery script to control table row(tr) move up/down.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#mytable a.move').click(function() 
{
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
{
    row.prev().before(row);
}
else
    row.next().after(row);
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="250" align="left" 
bgcolor="#eeeeee"  border="0" id="mytable">
<thead>
<tr class="tablebody">
  <th width="21" class="tablehead">S.No</th>
  <th width="119" class="tablehead">levels</th>
  <th width="100" class="tablehead">Sort</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="tablebody" id="status2">
  <td class="tdValue"> 1 </td>
  <td>level - 1 </td>
  <td width="100"><a class="move up" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images1/arrow_up.gif" alt="Up" width="11" height="13" border="0" /></a> <a class="move down" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images1/arrow_down.gif" alt="down" width="11" height="13" border="0" /></a> </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tablebody" id="status3">
  <td class="tdValue">  2 </td>
  <td>level - 2 </td>
  <td width="100"><a class="move up" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images1/arrow_up.gif" alt="Up" width="11" height="13" border="0" /></a> <a class="move down" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images1/arrow_down.gif" alt="down" width="11" height="13" border="0" /></a> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

I can able to move the tr up/down for "n" of TD's. but, can't able to change the s.no 2 to 1 after complete tr up/down.

or i want to move up/down only two TD's(levels and sort) not S.no TD

kindly provide me the detailed steps for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#mytable a.move').click(function()
    {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');

        if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
        {
            var preTr = row.prev(); // Get Previous TR
            var prevSN = preTr.find('td:eq(0)').html(); // Get Previous TR S.No
            row.find('td:eq(0)').html(prevSN); // Set To Current Row S.No
            preTr.find('td:eq(0)').html(Number(prevSN)+1); // Set To Previos S.No, Previous + 1
            preTr.before(row); //Change in DOM
        }
        else
        {
            var nextTr = row.next(); // Get Next TR
            var nextSN = nextTr .find('td:eq(0)').html(); // Get Next S.No
            row.find('td:eq(0)').html(nextSN ); // Set Next S.No. To Current Tr
            nextTr.find('td:eq(0)').html(Number(nextSN)-1); // Set Next S.No -1 To Next Tr
            nextTr.after(row); //Change in DOM
        }
    });

});
```

check this quick **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C9WRY/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.find()` method to get the td element with the `"tdValue"` class in each row and then use the `.html()` method to get and set their values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable a.move').click(function() {
        var up = $(this).hasClass('up'),
            thisRow = $(this).closest('tr'),
            thisTD = thisRow.find(".tdValue")
            thisSNo = thisTD.html(),
            otherRow = thisRow[up?"prev":"next"](),
            otherTD = otherRow.find(".tdValue");

        if(otherRow.length){
            thisTD.html(otherTD.html());
            otherTD.html(thisSNo);
            otherRow[up?"before":"after"](thisRow);
        }
    });
});
```

The `if(otherRow.length)` test is to avoid trying to go down from the bottom row or up from the top row.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/mKq5S/